# Event Listeners firing twice when used with jQuery

Tags: jquery, addeventlistener

I have this problem when using event listeners and jQuery. For some reason the events keep firing twice.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    function tioOverload(e){

        var tioButton = e.explicitOriginalTarget;       
        var path = tioButton.name;

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                path : path,
                action : "bpnsc_tio_enable"
            },
            success : function(data) {
            console.log('Success enabled ' + data);

            },
            error : function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log("failed");
            }
        });

    }

    var tioEn = document.getElementsByClassName("tio-enable");
    for (var i = 0; i < tioEn.length; i++) {
        tioEn[i].addEventListener('click',tioOverload);
    }
});
```

The PHP:

```
function bpnsc_tio_enable() {

    $path = $_POST['path'];
    echo $path;
    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_bpnsc_tio_enable', 'bpnsc_tio_enable');
```

and the HTML for the image I'm triggering the action from:

```
<img class="tio-enable" name="Test Feature" src="/image.png">
```

If I remove the jQuery and simply load the JavaScript on document.ready the event handler only fires once per mouseclick, with jQuery it is firing twice. I can't remove the jQuery because I need to use AJAX.

Comment: How can you tell they are being fired twice?

Comment: Put a console log message in the loop where you assign the click handler.  I suspect you'll see it's being executed twice and there's something somewhere else that's triggering it.

Comment: I put a console log in the event listener loop and it is indeed being fired twice.

Comment: Maybe you have two elements with `class="tio-enable"`...

Comment: I added to the loop a check to make sure it would only run once, but it failed to stop the event listener from being duplicated. I then tried using `removeEventLister()` to remove the extra listener but this did not work and the event continued to fire twice. I notice however that if I use `addEventLister()` in the loop it fires twice, if I use `removeEventListener()` in the loop it fires once. That at least would tend to suggest it's not being caused by duplicate elements since if that were the case both would fire twice.

Comment: At the bottom of `tioOverload()` add `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: e.stopPropagation has no impact on the observed behaviour.

Comment: I've done some more testing and it looks like the entire jQuery function is being fired twice.

Comment: I've stripped back the code and what I've discovered is that the following code causes the jQuery function to fire twice: ` for (var i = 0; i < tioDis.length; i++) {
  tioDis[i].addEventListener('click',tioDisable);
  console.log('listener added: '+tioDis[i].name);
 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".tio-enable").off().on('click', function(){
 // your code here
});
```

Use this code instead of looping through all the elements and attaching the events.

Hope this helps.